# How to speed up Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

How to speed up MST algorithm? I work with graphs and I have adopted Prim's algorithm for my needs, from [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/data/005430/0007/GreedyAlgorithmsForAMinimumSpanningTree/GreedyAlgorithmsForAMinimumSpanningTree-source.nb).

The graphs which I use are very dense (number of vertexes: $V=500$ and every vertex is connected with other $N-$1 vertexes).
For such graph my computer (i5 2500K@4.6GHz) needs about 40 seconds to compute MST (Prim).

I read this: [Performance Tuning in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721171/performance-tuning-in-mathematica)

What is the best way to optimize this code?

1. Compile? I tried this but I can't force it to work...
2. Maybe change some procedural parts of code to functional? If it possible, how?
   For me, Prim, seems to be procedural in its roots.
3. Or should I change algorithm to Kruskal or Boruvka?

For now, I successfully use `Parallelize` function, so I can compute many different graphs in parallel on 4 cores. But how make it faster when computing each single graph?

This is my code (adopted for my needs;):

```
getMstPrim[metricMatrix_] :=
 Module[{groupOne, groupTwo, kk, paths, current, rule = {}, n},
  n = Length[metricMatrix[[2]]];
  groupOne = {RandomInteger[{1, n}]} ;                               (* 
  initialaze from any points, groupOne is inside points of the tree *)
  groupTwo = Complement[Range[1, n], groupOne];           (* 
  groupTwo is outside points of the tree *)
  For[kk = 1, kk < n, kk++,
   paths = 
    Table[{metricMatrix[[i, j]], {i, j}}, {i, groupOne}, {j, 
      groupTwo}]; (* 
   current possible connections between group one and two *)
   current = Last[First[Sort[Flatten[paths, 1]]]];   (* 
   sort for shortest weight*)
   groupOne = Union[groupOne, current];                              (* 
   add the current path to goupe one *)
   groupTwo = Complement[groupTwo, current];                   (* 
   remove the current path from goupe two *)
   rule = 
    Append[rule, 
     current]                                                   (* 
   store the paths for final use *)
   ];
  rule
  ]
```

`metricMatrix` is list of lists (~500 x 100).

Comment: Have you seen the implementation of Kruskal's algorithm in the *Combinatorica* package?

Comment: I saw implementation from http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~sriram/Combinatorica/NewCombinatorica.m but it's not straightfoward. It uses many internal functions and uses graph objects different than in version 8. It seems similar...

Comment: Might try out Kruskal code [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConnectingTownsUsingKruskalsAlgorithm/)

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested looking at it, not using it. You might be able to modify the *Combinatorica* routine to then suit your needs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here we are given a set of points and start by computing distances between them; those will be our edge weights. If you already have edge weights then this preprocessing step is not needed. It is by far the bottleneck in the code below; the rest is a fraction of a second on 1000 vertices. Also I did not try to optimize the preprocessing (let alone the non-bottleneck parts) for speed e.g. using packable arrays and Compile.

So here is what might be a correct implementation of Prim's algorithm.

--- edit ---

I am replacing what I had with a corrected version, based on findings by the original poster. It uses a binary heap so I need code for that as well.

It will return the total length of the spanning tree as well as the list of edges. As before it takes a list of points in the plane, and the graph is by assumption the complete graph with vertices being the points and edge weights being the distance between the points. One can modify for other graphs without too much trouble.

I also coded in a slightly (more than usual) awkward way. The intent is to make it less difficult to use Compile. I do not have time to pursue that myself. As it stands, this seems to be around 4x slower than the Kruskal implementation I showed. At least the asymptotics look about right.

```
heapbottompointer = 1;
heaptoppointer = 2;
makeHeap[len_, elemsize_] := ConstantArray[0., {len + 1, elemsize}]

Clear[addToHeap, removeFromHeap]

SetAttributes[addToHeap, HoldFirst];
addToHeap[heap_, elem : {_Real, __}] := Module[
  {j1, j2},
  heap[[heapbottompointer, 1]] += 1;
  j1 = heap[[heapbottompointer, 1]];
  heap[[j1 + 1]] = elem;
  While[(j2 = Floor[j1/2]) >= 1 && 
    heap[[j2 + 1, 1]] > heap[[j1 + 1, 1]],
   heap[[{j1 + 1, j2 + 1}]] = heap[[{j2 + 1, j1 + 1}]];
   j1 = j2;
   ];
  ]

SetAttributes[removeFromHeap, HoldFirst];
removeFromHeap[heap_] := Module[
  {prev = 2, j1 = 2, j2 = 3, top = heap[[heaptoppointer]], last, next},
  last = heap[[heapbottompointer, 1]];
  While[j1 <= last,
   If[j2 <= last,
    next = If[heap[[j1 + 1, 1]] <= heap[[j2 + 1, 1]], j1, j2],
    next = j1
    ];
   heap[[prev]] = heap[[next + 1]];
   prev = next + 1;
   {j1, j2} = 2*next + {0, 1};
   ];
  heap[[heapbottompointer, 1]] -= 1;
  heap[[prev]] = heap[[last + 1]];
  j1 = prev - 1;
  While[(j2 = Floor[j1/2]) >= 1 && 
    heap[[j2 + 1, 1]] > heap[[j1 + 1, 1]],
   heap[[{j1 + 1, j2 + 1}]] = heap[[{j2 + 1, j1 + 1}]];
   j1 = j2;
   ];
  top
  ]

Prim[pts_] := Module[
  {edges, n = Length[pts], vert, heap, nedges = 1, tdist = 0., 
   treelist, top, used, verts, addedges},
  edges = Table[EuclideanDistance[pts[[i]], pts[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, n}];
  used = ConstantArray[False, n];
  used[[1]] = True;
  heap = makeHeap[n^2, 3];
  Do[
   addToHeap[heap, {edges[[1, j]], 1., N[j]}], {j, 2, n}];
  treelist = ConstantArray[{0, 0}, n - 1];
  While[heap[[1, 1]] >= 1 && nedges <= n - 1,
   top = removeFromHeap[heap];
   verts = Round[Rest[top]];
   If[used[[verts[[1]]]] && ! used[[verts[[2]]]] || ! 
       used[[verts[[1]]]] && used[[verts[[2]]]],
    If[! used[[verts[[1]]]] && used[[verts[[2]]]], 
     verts = Reverse[verts]];
    used[[verts[[2]]]] = True;
    tdist += top[[1]];
    treelist[[nedges]] = verts;
    nedges++;
    addedges = edges[[verts[[2]]]];
    Do[If[! used[[j]], 
      addToHeap[heap, {addedges[[j]], N[verts[[2]]], N[j]}]], {j, 
      n}];
    ]
   ];
  {tdist, treelist}
  ]
```

Example:

```
n = 1000;
pts = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {n, 2}];

Timing[tree = Prim[pts];]

(* {20.64, Null} *)
```

--- end edit ---

Alternatively, use Kruskal's algorithm. Same preprocessing as above is used here. Again, I beleive this is a correct implementation but caveat emptor.

```
Kruskal[pts_] := Module[
  {n = Length[pts], vpairs, jj = 0, hh, pair, dist, c1, c2, c1c2}, 
  Do[hh[k] = {k}, {k, n}];
  vpairs = 
   Sort[Flatten[
     Table[{(pts[[k]] - pts[[l]]).(pts[[k]] - pts[[l]]), {k, l}}, {k, 
       1, n - 1}, {l, k + 1, n}], 1]];
  First[Last[Reap[While[jj < Length[vpairs], jj++;
      {dist, pair} = vpairs[[jj]];
      {c1, c2} = {hh[pair[[1]]], hh[pair[[2]]]};
      If[c1 =!= c2, Sow[Apply[Rule, vpairs[[jj, 2]]]];
       c1c2 = Union[c1, c2];
       Do[hh[c1c2[[k]]] = c1c2, {k, Length[c1c2]}];
       If[Length[hh[pair[[1]]]] == n, Break[]];];]]]]]

Timing[krus = Kruskal[pts];]

(* Out[65]= {5.090000, Null} *)
```

--- edit 2021-05-16 ---

A proper implementation of the "lazy" version of Prim's algorithm will use a priority queue. Which is what I used above. The "eager" version, which tends to be faster, needs an indexed priority queue. A proper version of Kruskal's algorithm (which I did not quite achieve above) will use a data structure called a merge-find set. I have reference implementations of these data structures, along with minimum spanning tree examples, in the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/).

[PriorityQueue](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PriorityQueue/)

[IndexedQueue](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IndexedQueue/)

[MergeFindSet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MergeFindSet/)

None of these suffer from being blindingly fast. The merge-find set implementation of Kruskal's algorithm indeed seems to be slightly slower than the more naive implementation in this note. I do not know offhand what might be the bottleneck(s). Testing, as those the function pages will show, indicates at least that the asymptotics are as expected.

--- end edit ---

Comment: It might be expedient to use `SquaredEuclideanDistance[]` for generating `vpairs`...

Comment: @J.M. Good idea; cuts time in half, roughly. But I'm off to bed. If I try to edit it first I'll just get it all wrong, and start spewing maximal spanning subway systems.

Comment: Thanks! It takes 3 seconds to compute, instead of 40. Thats efficient :) But I can't get the same results as before (for the same matrix). BTW I need only a list of pairs so I changed ' Sow[Apply[Rule, pair]] ' to 'Sow[pair]' and so on. I tested it like that: (PrimOld@matrix) // Flatten // Sort ==(PrimNew@matrix) // Flatten //Sort. Generated lists are different. SortSquaredEuclideanDistance[] would not work because weights in my matrix are not Euclidean distances, just some correlations between vertices. So, why the results of those 2 algorithms are different?

Comment: I skimmed over the Wikipedia article the other evening to figure out how to code Prim's algorithm. There's a good chance I got it wrong. I'll try to look again (next week, after our conference winds down).

Comment: OK. Maybe till then I will figure it out what's wrong with one of them. Thanks again :)

Comment: I checked that Kruskal implementation from your link (and also answer) Daniel. It works. I got the same result (MST) like in algorithm that I posted. Results? 0.5s instead of 39, for 560x560matrix. I'll think about your 'Prim' solution. I'm curious why the result is different...

Comment: **I found an error** in your Prim algorithm. You forgot that after we find a pair we should start over search the list of vpairs, because we probably missed some of pairs in which none of two vertices was inTree. To avoid it we can for example delete elements from vpairs, but IIRC deleting one by one is inefficient.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a mistake I made (there may be others, I guess). I need to think about whether there is a straightforward way to repair this without completely messing up efficiency.

Comment: Thank you! I use Kruskal, but I will definitely study this _slightly awkward_ implementation. Some new concepts to learn;)

Comment: I rewrote the Kruskal in a less procedural fashion, it became slightly faster. (.57s vs 1.38s for n=500) This takes vpairs as argument. `Kruskal[vpairs_] :=
 Block[{hh, c1c2},
  (* hh[k] gives all vertices in same set as k, default alone *)
  
  Attributes[hh] = {Listable};
  hh[k_Integer] := {k};
  (* For each edge in order, remove it if connection within same set.
  Otherwise keep edge and join the sets*)
  Rule @@@ Select[
    vpairs[[All, 2]],
    If[Equal @@ hh[#1], False,
      c1c2 = DeleteDuplicates@(Flatten[hh[#1], 1]);
      Scan[(hh[#1] = c1c2) &, c1c2];
      True
      ] &]
  ]`

Comment: @ssch Interesting. While I realize procedural code is sometimes a cause of inefficiency in Mathematica, I'd not have expected it to be a factor of 2+ in this case. Useful improvement, that.