# Changing some stuff to Kruskal's Algorithm

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I'm trying to modify this algorithm:
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConnectingTownsUsingKruskalsAlgorithm/

The thing is that I want to receive a Graph (declared outside, with all its vertex, edges and weights) in the Kruskal's function and start from there, using maybe a WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[G] and sort the weights and returning them.
It's just a practice I want to do, because I'm learning Mathematica, so I'm still a noob with this. To  be more specific with my question, I just want to know where and how I can replace parts from the code, with the things I mentioned above. This is my idea, of course without the Kruskal's implementation:

```
G = Graph[{a \[UndirectedEdge] b, a \[UndirectedEdge] d, 
a \[UndirectedEdge] f, b \[UndirectedEdge] c, 
b \[UndirectedEdge] d, b \[UndirectedEdge] e, 
c \[UndirectedEdge] e, c \[UndirectedEdge] g, 
d \[UndirectedEdge] e, d \[UndirectedEdge] f, 
d \[UndirectedEdge] g, e \[UndirectedEdge] g, 
f \[UndirectedEdge] g}, 
EdgeWeight -> {5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2}, 
VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10] 
Kruskal[G]
```

Comment: Sorry José, but I can't understand _"I just want to know where and how I can replace parts from the code"_ Can you explain that further?

Comment: And welcome! I think you're our first Tico around!

Comment: Yeah sorry for not explaining it well, and thanks for your welcome. I think I did a mess actually. I want to change the implementation of the function, I want it to receive the Graph, with its vertex, edges, and weights. And find the MinimumSpanningTree. It's like implementing the MinimumSpanningTree function actually, step by step. I was looking for the Combinatorica implemntation but I need to have it into one same function. Sorry if I'm not explaining it well! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13160)?

Comment: Yes, and thanks ! But what does pts mean?

Comment: I have read it all, and now I know what pts mean, I'll see what can I do to it...Because I'm creating the graph with its weights, so I just need it to receive the graph

Comment: If you solve your own question, please remember to post the answer

Comment: I hope to solve it! I have a sample of a Prim's algorithm the same way I want the Kruskal's, but it is long as hell...Do you speak spanish Belisarius? Maybe I can send it to you by mail if you want (the prim's sample the teacher gave us)

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know that I understand you correctly. You have some graph G in structure Graph. Then you want to use MST (Prim/Kruskal) algorithm to obtain changed G which is MST graph.
I tried that but it didn't work in M8.

Here is how I did that the other way:

1. I prepared graph in nested list `graph` (matrix nxn), where `graph[[i,j]]` are weights between i and j vertices. Of course that matrix, in principle, should be symmetric and weights `graph[[i,i]]` should be 0.
2. I use MST algorithm on that matrix, for example Kruskal:

   ```
    kruskal[pts_] := 
     Module[{n = Length[pts[[2]]], vpairs, jj = 0, hh, pair, dist, c1, c2,
   c1c2}, Do[hh[k] = {k}, {k, n}];
   vpairs=Sort[Flatten[
    Table[{pts[[k, l]], {k, l}}, {k, 1, n - 1}, {l, k + 1, n}], 1]];
    First[Last[Reap[While[jj < Length[vpairs], jj++;
     {dist, pair} = vpairs[[jj]];
     {c1, c2} = {hh[pair[[1]]], hh[pair[[2]]]};
     If[c1 =!= c2, Sow[vpairs[[jj, 2]]];
      c1c2 = Union[c1, c2];
      Do[hh[c1c2[[k]]] = c1c2, {k, Length[c1c2]}];
      If[Length[hh[pair[[1]]]] == n, Break[]];];]]]]]
   ```
3. Use that Kruskal function on your matrix: `kruskal@graph`.
   Function return list of pairs, something like: {{2,5},{5,7},...}
4. Then you must change that list to object that can be understand by Graph function in Mathematica. Use that function:

   ```
   mstListToEdge[mstList_] := mstList /. {x_, y_} :> x \[UndirectedEdge] y
   ```
5. In the end use list from 4. and `graph` matrix to generate Graph. You will obtain MST graph picture with weights.

   ```
   graphMst[edges_, graph_] :=
    Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10, 
     GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding",
     EdgeWeight -> 
      Array[graph[[edges[[#, 1]], 
         edges[[#, 2]]]] & (*mstWeights *), Length@edges]]
   ```