# Combinatorica vs Built-in functions: Use of MinimumSpanningTree

Tags: graphs-and-networks

What kind of argument is expected by `MinimumSpanningTree` (from the package `` Combinatorica` ``)? Is it possible that I am providing the right kind of argument, but that conflict between usual definitions and definitions from the package `` Combinatorica` `` prevents correct evaluation?

Note that, conform the documentation page of `FindShortestPath`,

```
graph = System`PetersenGraph[4, 1, EdgeWeight -> {4, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 6}]
```

Produces some weighted graph. We can then do

```
FindShortestPath[graph, 1, 3]
```

which works as expected. Note that if we use `` Combinatorica`PetersenGraph `` this will not work. Anyway, I would expect `MinimumSpanningTree` to work on at least one of the two graphs generated this way. Unfortunately, I cannot get it it to work. I have been unable to get `MimimumSpanningTree` to work on any graph so far.

Remarks

The documentation center provides very little information on `MimimumSpanningTree`. The `PetersenGraph` may not be a very nice example, as *Mathematica* seems to point out an error in the syntax even before the package `` Combinatorica` `` is loaded. However, upon asking the `FullForm` of the result, everything seems to be as we expect it to be.

**Edit**: Can I assume there is no efficient way to let `MinimumSpanningTree` calculate a minimum spanning tree between many points in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I suppose that for this, one should refer to [How to speed up Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13160/). As a test I entered a huge graph in `MinimumSpanningTree`, but an algorithm by Daniel Lichtblau was faster.

Comment: Woring within the Combinatorica package with Mma 7, `Needs["Combinatorica`"]` `ShowGraph@MinimumSpanningTree@PetersenGraph` and `NumberOfSpanningTrees@PetersenGraph` => 2000

Comment: Nice, thanks! Note though that the graph that is displayed in the first case is not a minimum spanning tree in the sense that the Euclidean distance of all the edges is minimized.

Comment: related post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13160/how-to-speed-up-minimum-spanning-tree-algorithm

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33857/minimum-spanning-tree-from-a-weighted-adjacency-graph      and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33882/1997

Comment: @ubpdqn ah, thank you, maybe there is some duplication going on. If Combinatorica really is obsolete, then that is another argument to close.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Although the in-built functions are excellent but there are areas and occasions that `Combinatorica` has something. In that case you have to deal with context, hence my answer. Sadly, me answer (which I believe works)  which explores going between contexts was not up to par. The alternative approaches in that question are excellent. The cross posting on community has a very nice answer by Vitaliy Kaurov and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am working within the [Combinatorica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/guide/CombinatoricaPackage.html) package with Mma 7.

Also, I am not by any means an expert here, but I am interested in the question posed.  What follows is an attempt at obtaining a minimum spanning tree from a weighted [Petersen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) graph

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

Generate a weighted [Peterson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) graph (shown on the left below)

```
edgeRuleList = {#[[1]], EdgeWeight -> #[[2]]} & /@ 
   Transpose[{Edges@PetersenGraph, {4, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 
      6, 1, 1, 1}}];

myWeightedPetersonGraph = 
  SetGraphOptions[PetersenGraph, edgeRuleList];

ShowGraph[myWeightedPetersonGraph, VertexLabel -> True, 
 VertexLabelPosition -> Center, VertexStyle -> Disk[Large], 
 VertexColor -> LightYellow, EdgeColor -> Red, 
 VertexNumberColor -> Black, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}]
```

where

```
Edges@myWeightedPetersonGraph
```

=> {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 
  10}, {6, 10}, {1, 6}, {2, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 9}, {5, 10}}

and

```
GetEdgeWeights@myWeightedPetersonGraph
```

=> {4, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1}

Generate the minimum spanning tree from weighted [Peterson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) (shown on right below)

```
myMinSpanningTree = 
 ShowGraph[MinimumSpanningTree@myWeightedPetersonGraph, 
  VertexLabel -> True, VertexLabelPosition -> Center, 
  VertexStyle -> Disk[Large], VertexColor -> LightYellow, 
  EdgeColor -> Red, VertexNumberColor -> Black, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}]
```

Graphs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems very nice and to the point. I am considering accepting it, but first let me see if I can get it to work for other graphs.

Comment: See also SetEdgeWeights