# Creating a Network from a Output

Tags: graphs-and-networks

So I used the locator pane to derive the positions of a vertex on a picture. The picture was the Maryland Power Grid and the vertices were the generators and loads of the power system. When I clicked the vertex and recorded it returned this (Vertex number {x-pos,y-pos}). After recording all the vertices I have a list of data and from this list I would like to graphically plot this network with their relative coordinates. From the output I would like to graphically create a  minimum spanning network with the loads as either a certain color/shape and the generators as another distinct color and shape. From this I would like to run calculations such as Monte Carlo Simulations, create an adjacency matrix, and possibly even mess around with Markov Random Fields. I need help figuring out how to graphically represent it with color/shape distinctions between the loads and generators and produce a minimum spanning network from the output I received.
The Input code was:

```
im= Import["http://esm.versar.com/pprp/ceir16/Images/Figure2_20.jpg"];
Module[{picturesize,i,bigger,imagesizes},
picturesize=675;
values={};
i=1;
imagesizes=ImageDimensions[im];bigger=1;
DynamicModule[{pt={0,0}},
If[imagesizes[[1]]<imagesizes[[2]], bigger=2];
TableForm@{
    Button["Record!",AppendTo[values,{i,pt}];i++;],
    LocatorPane[
        Dynamic@pt,
        Dynamic@Graphics[
            Join[
                {Inset[im,{0,0},{0,0},{1,1}]}
                
            ],
        PlotRange->{{0,imagesizes[[1]]/imagesizes[[bigger]]},{0,imagesizes[[2]]/imagesizes[[bigger]]}},
        ImageSize->picturesize]
],
Dynamic[N@pt],
Dynamic[MatrixForm@values]
}]
]
```

[image]

The Output was:

```
({
  {1, {0.0996, 0.4195}},
  {2, {0.1046, 0.392}},
  {3, {0.1144, 0.468}},
  {4, {0.1164, 0.4415}},
  {5, {0.1432, 0.4455}},
  {6, {0.1442, 0.376}},
  {7, {0.147, 0.5085}},
  {8, {0.16, 0.4965}},
  {9, {0.1628, 0.5305}},
  {10, {0.1708, 0.484}},
  {11, {0.1776, 0.379}},
  {12, {0.1836, 0.4335}},
  {13, {0.1856, 0.408}},
  {14, {0.1936, 0.4495}},
  {15, {0.2034, 0.5295}},
  {16, {0.1974, 0.3595}},
  {17, {0.2122, 0.4395}},
  {18, {0.2152, 0.4465}},
  {19, {0.2252, 0.3555}},
  {20, {0.229, 0.4415}},
  {21, {0.2716, 0.3535}},
  {22, {0.2952, 0.313}},
  {23, {0.3258, 0.4265}},
  {24, {0.3446, 0.475}},
  {25, {0.3476, 0.4315}},
  {26, {0.3536, 0.408}},
  {27, {0.3584, 0.3545}},
  {28, {0.3694, 0.3665}},
  {29, {0.3732, 0.384}},
  {30, {0.393, 0.3535}},
  {31, {0.395, 0.4205}},
  {32, {0.4028, 0.3625}},
  {33, {0.4028, 0.378}},
  {34, {0.4088, 0.3525}},
  {35, {0.4108, 0.4345}},
  {36, {0.4286, 0.4505}},
  {37, {0.4336, 0.405}},
  {38, {0.4434, 0.247}},
  {39, {0.4542, 0.303}},
  {40, {0.4532, 0.4415}},
  {41, {0.4612, 0.3515}},
  {42, {0.469, 0.3455}},
  {43, {0.47, 0.3685}},
  {44, {0.477, 0.391}},
  {45, {0.4888, 0.31}},
  {46, {0.4948, 0.3315}},
  {47, {0.4958, 0.371}},
  {48, {0.4986, 0.217}},
  {49, {0.4918, 0.4375}},
  {50, {0.5214, 0.376}},
  {51, {0.5244, 0.3455}},
  {52, {0.5284, 0.4315}},
  {53, {0.5294, 0.457}},
  {54, {0.5302, 0.471}},
  {55, {0.5302, 0.2875}},
  {56, {0.554, 0.243}},
  {57, {0.554, 0.323}},
  {58, {0.554, 0.299}},
  {59, {0.559, 0.231}},
  {60, {0.559, 0.2575}},
  {61, {0.559, 0.2725}},
  {62, {0.5628, 0.244}},
  {63, {0.5668, 0.221}},
  {64, {0.5668, 0.316}},
  {65, {0.5708, 0.1755}},
  {66, {0.5816, 0.2665}},
  {67, {0.5836, 0.224}},
  {68, {0.5916, 0.152}},
  {69, {0.5806, 0.307}},
  {70, {0.5826, 0.3365}},
  {71, {0.5876, 0.32}},
  {72, {0.5974, 0.242}},
  {73, {0.5984, 0.2845}},
  {74, {0.6044, 0.2865}},
  {75, {0.5856, 0.397}},
  {76, {0.5906, 0.3605}},
  {77, {0.5916, 0.388}},
  {78, {0.6014, 0.3385}},
  {79, {0.6054, 0.388}},
  {80, {0.6132, 0.299}},
  {81, {0.6132, 0.2865}},
  {82, {0.6142, 0.2745}},
  {83, {0.6182, 0.375}},
  {84, {0.6252, 0.245}},
  {85, {0.6252, 0.3355}},
  {86, {0.629, 0.3605}},
  {87, {0.63, 0.371}},
  {88, {0.63, 0.388}},
  {89, {0.633, 0.474}},
  {90, {0.635, 0.3535}},
  {91, {0.641, 0.3525}},
  {92, {0.639, 0.411}},
  {93, {0.6438, 0.3585}},
  {94, {0.6458, 0.4355}},
  {95, {0.6488, 0.473}},
  {96, {0.6548, 0.2695}},
  {97, {0.6576, 0.38}},
  {98, {0.6646, 0.4455}},
  {99, {0.6736, 0.3685}},
  {100, {0.6764, 0.4415}},
  {101, {0.6774, 0.396}},
  {102, {0.6902, 0.402}},
  {103, {0.6932, 0.373}},
  {104, {0.6962, 0.473}},
  {105, {0.6972, 0.453}},
  {106, {0.718, 0.389}},
  {107, {0.7268, 0.292}},
  {108, {0.7228, 0.4335}},
  {109, {0.7288, 0.457}},
  {110, {0.7426, 0.296}},
  {111, {0.7406, 0.4235}},
  {112, {0.7644, 0.295}},
  {113, {0.7624, 0.457}},
  {114, {0.7802, 0.4225}},
  {115, {0.7802, 0.2855}},
  {116, {0.7822, 0.3355}},
  {117, {0.797, 0.4315}},
  {118, {0.799, 0.4495}},
  {119, {0.8028, 0.4415}},
  {120, {0.8168, 0.1235}},
  {121, {0.8088, 0.459}},
  {122, {0.8226, 0.1045}},
  {123, {0.8186, 0.3465}},
  {124, {0.8168, 0.468}},
  {125, {0.8286, 0.244}},
  {126, {0.8256, 0.2825}},
  {127, {0.8266, 0.329}},
  {128, {0.8226, 0.38}},
  {129, {0.8196, 0.4345}},
  {130, {0.8394, 0.167}},
  {131, {0.8532, 0.291}},
  {132, {0.8602, 0.1245}},
  {133, {0.8652, 0.1085}},
  {134, {0.8898, 0.166}},
  {135, {0.8938, 0.133}},
  {136, {0.9164, 0.221}},
  {137, {0.9244, 0.153}},
  {138, {0.9284, 0.1845}},
  {139, {0.1076, 0.4125}},
  {140, {0.1224, 0.3445}},
  {141, {0.15, 0.4205}},
  {142, {0.4028, 0.4215}},
  {143, {0.4642, 0.33}},
  {144, {0.467, 0.3395}},
  {145, {0.5362, 0.242}},
  {146, {0.548, 0.2525}},
  {147, {0.5638, 0.131}},
  {148, {0.6102, 0.1775}},
  {149, {0.629, 0.3435}},
  {150, {0.64, 0.456}},
  {151, {0.6458, 0.317}},
  {152, {0.6488, 0.3535}},
  {153, {0.6508, 0.385}},
  {154, {0.6538, 0.3365}},
  {155, {0.6636, 0.328}},
  {156, {0.6626, 0.161}},
  {157, {0.6764, 0.3555}},
  {158, {0.6854, 0.456}},
  {159, {0.7002, 0.465}},
  {160, {0.708, 0.387}},
  {161, {0.715, 0.4345}},
  {162, {0.716, 0.2635}},
  {163, {0.7812, 0.1815}},
  {164, {0.8958, 0.1925}}
 })
```

So finally got it to work:

```
graphicslist = 
  Table[Rectangle[mpg[[i, 2]] , mpg[[i, 2]] + {.005, .005}], {i, 1, Length@mpg}];
  Graphics[graphicslist]
```

And it returned:
[image]

Now I want a way to get the minimum spanning tree and from there get the adjacency matrix. Any Ideas?

Comment: I haven't coded anything because I have this list, or matrix, or vertices positions and want to make a minimum spanning network from this. And from this minimum spanning network I would like to run calculations such as Monte Carlo simulations.

Comment: So for example I don't know what a "minimum spanning network" is. (BTW I didn't downvote you -- not at all trying to be nasty.) This site has a lot of MMA expertise but people's backgrounds are quite different. The more you can tell us about your problem the more likely it is someone will be able to provide constructive input.

Comment: Im trying to use Prim's algorithm if that helps.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I can see why that happened.  The question doesn't contain enough relevant information, but it does contain a lot of irrelevant information.  If you're asking how to create a `Graph` object, then it is completely irrelevant that *afterwards* you want to do a Monte Carlo simulation, find a minimum spanning tree or use Prim's algorithm.  At the same time you didn't explain clearly what kind of data you have (your input).  Give a clear example input and example output.

Comment: http://esm.versar.com/pprp/ceir16/Images/Figure2_20.jpg

Comment: If rasher's answer is what you needed, then the essential piece missing was saying that you are interested in a complete graph, with edge weights assigned based on geometrical distances between points.  I have the impression that you are not sure yourself what you need to do.  Why don't you discuss this with your supervisor, and understand the problem fully before asking about the solution here?

Comment: @David: Updated my answer with example using points from your update ... is that what you're after?

Comment: I appreciate the graph rasher but I really want to learn Mathematica rather than copy other peoples code, that is why Im updating you guys with what I get after a couple hours of learning things.

Comment: @David: Well then, you have everything you need. Build a graph with edge weights of euclidean distance (or whatever metric is appropriate), then run your MST algorithm on it. The `Combinatorica` package has min. span. tree etc, but you need to use *its* graph structures. *Mathematica* lacks built-in MST other than that. Perhaps perusing the linked code might give you some pointers on implementing your own if that's your bag...

Comment: You can also self-answer your question once you´re all set. But if you do not want to "copy" code, asking here is a bit contradictory, because most users are bound to post code.

Comment: I was wondering if any of you know how to create a minimum spanning tree and how to distinct from loads/generators by making them two distinct shapes rather than just squares as points

Comment: @david: As you no doubt see, this is perilously close to getting closed. Now you've asked "how to create a minimum spanning tree", when prior you've said you were "trying to use Prim's algorithm..." Which is it? If you don't know the algorithms, plenty of texts and internet resources to learn them, then code them. As for how to delineate generators from loads, where is that information in your points data? In any case, a simple read of the documentation will illuminate how to control vertex characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

Using *Daniel Lichtblau*'s [prim algorithm code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13184/11467) :

```
(* fake some points *)
n = 10;
pts = RandomReal[{0, 50}, {n, 2}];

tree = Prim[pts];

Graph[Range@n, UndirectedEdge @@@ tree[[2]], VertexCoordinates -> pts, VertexLabels -> "Name",
      ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Here's your points from your update (I left out labels - image needs to be large so they don't overlap, and wouldn't be appropriate to post):
[image]